# Can't connect to Parse with Swift in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, swift

I write a app with Swift, and I also use Cocoapods with latest Parse SDK.

I test Parse in "Simulator" with some methods such as

> PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground
>
> query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

and everything is fine.

But, when I test in "iPhone", I can not connect to Parse. It just call the method, and there is no response, you can only see spinner in status bar.

I updated my iPhone to iOS 8.0, and it works. How to make it work on iOS 7 ?

Comment: This is all too vague. Why not show some code.

Comment: I have three different apps based on Parse SDK, none of those working. Have you tried to use Parse SDK on iPhone with iOS 7?

Comment: There are a few weird issues with the current Parse SDK and swift that are known, this one included. I would wait until they deploy an updated SDK that has been tested with swift.

Answer (score -1):

you have to set **`ApplicationId`** and **`ClientKey`** in AppDelegate 's *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method

Comment: did you imported all the frameworks needed to make Parse work ? and also check is there any data in your parse class on parse.com

Comment: Yes, everything imported. I just checked, Parse knows about this issue